# How to hide beamer subsections from the table of contents for non highlighted sections only

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, overleaf, subsection

This question has been asked several times but not in the same context as mine.

I have a beamer presentation with an initial table of contents frame for which I hide the subsections with the following code:

```
\begin{frame}{Outline of talk}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

In addition, I have a highlighted table of contents before each section, using the following code:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

My question: how to hide the subsections for all except the highlighted section in this at begin section slides.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was an easy one by simply using `hideothersubsections` option, like this:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
    \end{frame}
}
```